# How to get asp TextBox value into html input tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I was wondering how to get the value from the TextBox *"AddressTexBox"* and set it to the value of the input tag *"txtAutocomplete"*. Any help would be awesome. Thank You!!!

```
<input type="text" id="txtAutocomplete"  name ="txtauto" style="width: 900px" onkeypress = "fillAddress" />&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <asp:Label ID="AddressVerifyLabel" Text=" Verify Address: " runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="AddressTextBox" Columns="20" MaxLength="20" Width="600" runat="server" OnTextChanged ="fillAddress" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: adding the function "fillAddress" (which is a c# function) to the input "txtAutocomplete" whenever there is a text change would be just as helpful

Answer (score 0):

one way is to do it with javascript with `onchange` event

```
<input type="text" id="txtAutocomplete"  name ="txtauto" style="width: 900px"  />
<input type="text" id="AddressTextBox" onchange="myFunction()"  name ="txtauto" style="width: 900px"  />

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("AddressTextBox").value = document.getElementById("txtAutocomplete").value ;
}
</script>
```

and another was is to do with c# in backend

```
<input type="text" id="txtAutocomplete" runat = "server"  name ="txtauto" style="width: 900px" onkeypress = "fillAddress" />
```

and on `OnTextChanged`  event

```
txtAutocomplete.Value = AddressTextBox.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want to do, so I will provide 2 options. And `asp:TextBox` and `input type="text"` are the same thing in HTML. View the page source and see for yourself.

First is to get the value from `AddressTextBox` to `txtAutocomplete` using the `OnTextChanged` event. For that to work you will have to make `txtAutocomplete` an aspnet TextBox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAutocomplete" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="AddressTextBox" runat="server" OnTextChanged="fillAddress" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

And then in code behind

```
protected void fillAddress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtAutocomplete.Text = AddressTextBox.Text;
}
```

The second option is to use JavaScript, as @Usman also suggests. Unless there is more going on in `fillAddress` than we know of, this is the better solution since it does not do a PostBack and thus saves a roundtrip to the server. But I still suggest you make `txtAutocomplete` an aspnet TextBox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAutocomplete" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="AddressTextBox" runat="server" onkeydown="myFunction()"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("<%= txtAutocomplete.ClientID %>").value = document.getElementById("<%= AddressTextBox.ClientID %>").value;
    }
</script>
```

Note the use of `<%= txtAutocomplete.ClientID %>`. Aspnet changes the ID of Controls to something like this `ctl00$mainContentPane$AddressTextBox`. So if you would use `document.getElementById("AddressTextBox").value` JavaScript will not find the element and throw an error.